# Recursive least square with incomplete data

Tags: missing-data, online-algorithms

If we have a system

$\mathbf{Y}_t = \mathbf{A}_0 + \mathbf{v}_t$,

in which $\mathbf{v}_t$ is the noise. Using the first $t$ samples, we can estimate $\mathbf{A}_0$ by the arithmetic (sample) mean, i.e.,

$\hat{\mathbf{A}}_t = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t\mathbf{Y}_i$,

or we can write it in a recursive form

$\hat{\mathbf{A}}_{t} = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^{t}\mathbf{Y}_i = \hat{\mathbf{A}}_{t-1} + \frac{1}{t}(\mathbf{Y}_t - \hat{\mathbf{A}}_{t-1})$.

My question is that if $\mathbf{Y}_t$ is complete, for example,

$\mathbf{Y}_t = [1, 2, 1,1, NaN]^T$

then how should we run the recursive algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is any alternative to removing the times where $Y_t$ is missing, could you explain what it might be?

Comment: @whuber thanks for you comments. It is convenient to remove $Y_t$ with incomplete observations, however, in terms of saving the information that carried by the data, I prefer to keep them.

Comment: That's fine--but doesn't ignoring the incomplete observations solve your problem entirely?